# Need to index column in AND statement?

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have to do a SELECT on a table like this:

- id
- username
- speed
- is_running

The statement is like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE username = 'foo' 
   AND is_running = 1
```

I have an index on "username". If I'm running the above statement, do I need to also index "is_running" for best performance? Or does only the first column of the select make a difference? I'm using mysql 5.0.

Comment: assuming that `is_running` is boolean, an index won't make a difference because there aren't enough possibilities.

Comment: What is the username index selectivity? (ie How many total rows, and how many unique usernames are there)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of data you're storing. If it's bool, you may not see a gain from an index on that column alone. You may want to try to add a composite index on the two columns:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX `IDX_USERNAME_IS_RUNNING` ( `username` , `is_running` );
```

Comment: +1: Not so much about the data type, but the data itself.  A low cardinality column is not a candidate for an index -- an even 50/50 split of rows that are 1 or zero is useless.

Answer (score 0):

It will ultimately depend on the amount of data in the table as to if you require the index.  In many cases, the engine might just do a table scan and omit your index all together if it thinks that is faster.  Do you have 100 users, or 100,000 users?

On a bit/bool column you are not going to utilize a ton of storage space for the index, so it probably won't hurt unless you have a really high insertion rate.

Comment: MySQL ignores indexes if it expects to get more than 
30% hits so it will likely be ignored unless the distribution is very skewed.

Comment: @dnagirl - I've seen instances where the MySQL optimizer decides to use an index even if a scan would be faster. You can force this behavior by specifying which index to use or to ignore them...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table with 1 million users and only 1 or 2 is running at any one time - sure, index by is_running and it will give you fantastic performance.  This specific use case would do best to have 2 indexes *individually* on columns - username, isrunning.  The reason for 2 indexes is if you are asking for `is_running=0`, in which case it uses the `username` index instead.

Otherwise, there is 0% chance of a composite index on (username, isrunning) helping anything.  Stick to a single index on username.

Finally, do you really need to whole record? Select *?  In some scenarios close to the `tipping point` (when MySQL **thinks** the index+lookups becomes less efficient than a straight scan), you can make this query run faster than the original.  Have an index on (username,id)

```
SELECT mytable.*
FROM (
SELECT id 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE username = 'foo' 
   AND is_running = 1
) X
INNER JOIN mytable on mytable.id = X.id
```